# Reference in container?

Tags: c++, reference

I'm having an issue with passing a string as reference to a lambda, when it is in a container. I guess it disappears (goes out of scope) when I call the `init()` function, but why? And then, why doesn't it disappear when I just pass it as a string reference?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Foo {
  void init(int num, const std::string& txt)
  {
    this->num = num;
    this->txt = txt;
  }

  int num;
  std::string txt;
};

int main()
{
  auto codegen1 = [](std::pair<int, const std::string&> package) -> Foo* {
    auto foo = new Foo;
    foo->init(package.first, package.second); //here string goes out of scope, exception
    return foo;
  };

  auto codegen2 = [](int num, const std::string& txt) -> Foo* {
    auto foo = new Foo;
    foo->init(num, txt);
    return foo;
  };

  auto foo = codegen1({3, "text"});
  auto foo2 = codegen2(3, "text");
  std::cout << foo->txt;
}
```

I know the way to go would be to use `const std::pair<int, std::string>&`, but I want to understand why this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Is `std::reference_wrapper` what you are looking for?

Comment: Now I just tried out again, in VS Studio 2019 and it runs without exception. In Qt creator it throws an exception. I'm more confused than before lol.

Comment: @Mat fwiw, clang won't even let that compile at all. This example is interacting with quite a few very confusing/convoluted parts of the language all at once. I'm kind of impressed tbh.

Comment: @Frank it does because template deduction makes it `std::pair<int, const char*>` or `<int, const char[5]>` which then makes the target type out of it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Part 1**: This looks busted at a glance.

`"text"` is not a string, it's a literal that is being used to create a temporary `std::string` object, which is then used to initialize the `std::pair`. So you'd think it would make sense that the string, which is only needed transiently (i.e only until the `std::pair` is constructed), is gone by the time it is being referred to.

**Part 2**: But it shouldn't be busted.

However, temporaries that are created as part of an expression are supposed to be guaranteed to live until the end of the current "full-expression" (simplified: until the semicolon).

That's why the call to `codegen2()` works fine. A temporary `std::string` is created, and it stays alive until the call to `codegen2()` is complete.

**Part 3**: Yet it is busted, in this case.

So why does the string get destroyed prematurely in `codegen1()`'s case? The conversion from `"text"` to `std::string` does not happen as a sub-expression, but as part of a separate function being called with its own scope.

The constructor of `std::pair` that is being used here is:

```
// Initializes first with std::forward<U1>(x) and second with std::forward<U2>(y).
template< class U1 = T1, class U2 = T2 >
constexpr pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );
```

The constructor gets `"text"` as a parameter and the construction of the `std::string` is being done **inside** of `std::pair`'s constructor, so the temporary variable created as part of that process gets cleaned up when we return from that constructor.

The funny thing is, if that constructor did not exist, `std::pair`'s basic constructor: `pair( const T1& x, const T2& y );` would handle this just fine. The implicit conversion to `std::string` would be done prior to invoking the constructor.

**How do we fix this?**

There's a few alternatives:

Force the conversion to happen at the right "level":

```
auto foo = codegen1({3, std::string("text")});
```

Effectively the same thing, but with a nicer syntax:

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
auto foo = codegen1({3, "text"s});
```

Use a `std::string_view`, which removes the need for the conversion altogether:

```
auto codegen1 = [](std::pair<int, std::string_view> package) -> Foo* {
...
}
```

Though, in your case, since `Foo` will take ownership of the string, passing it by value and *moving* it around is clearly the way to go (I also took the liberty to clean up the code a bit):

```
struct Foo {
  Foo(int num, std::string txt)
    : num(num)
    , txt(std::move(txt))
  {}

  int num;
  std::string txt;
};

int main()
{
  auto codegen1 = [](std::pair<int, std::string> package) {
    return std::make_unique<Foo>(package.first, std::move(package.second));
  };

  auto foo = codegen1({3, "text"});

  std::cout << foo->txt;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, in C++14 and later: `{3, "text"s}` just add `using namespace std::literals::string_literals;` before it.